# Insert newline in continuous text based on pattern

Tags: awk, sed, tr

I gave a csv file which has records like

```
1. abc^123-01^NA^xyz 70            
   %^11-Sep-12^15-Apr-08^M
2. def^345^NA^NAME^01/10/2006^04/01/2007^M
3. ghi^234-01^NA^company 70
   %^19-Oct-20^04-Jun-07^M
4. jkl^72403831^NA^Org^13-Mar-11^26-Mar-08^M
5. 3251^2345^NA^SOLN., 10
   %^31-Dec-20^01-Apr-07^M
```

I checked the file using "od -c file" and the character at the end of line 1, 3 and 5 is \n. Double checked in Hex editor that it is OA. This file when ingested causes records to be truncated wherever the newline occurs in Line 1, 3 and 5. 
I have tried to delete all new lines using tr -delete '\n' which gives me below: tr --delete < file>file1

```
abc^123-01^NA^xyz 70%^11-Sep-12^15-Apr-  08^Mdef^345^NA^NAME^01/10/2006^04/01/2007^Mghi^234-01^NA^company 70%^19-Oct-20^04-Jun-07^Mjkl^72403831^NA^Org^13-Mar-11^26-Mar-08^M3251^2345^NA^SOLN., 10%^31-Dec-20^01-Apr-07^M
```

I am trying to insert newline at the ^M character to get my lines correctly. Can anyone give any ideas on how to accomplish this. 
I have tried below:

```
tr '^M' '^M\n' <file  
sed 's/^M/\n/g' file
```

None of the above work. I dont have much familiarity with awk, but am checking in awk too. I am looking to hear about ideas to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: `This file when ingested...` - ingested by what? awk and other text-processing tools would have no problem handling a file like that as-is.

Answer (score 0):

here you go...

```
$ tr -d '\n' <file | tr '\r' '\n' 

1. abc^123-01^NA^xyz 70               %^11-Sep-12^15-Apr-08
2. def^345^NA^NAME^01/10/2006^04/01/2007
3. ghi^234-01^NA^company 70   %^19-Oct-20^04-Jun-07
4. jkl^72403831^NA^Org^13-Mar-11^26-Mar-08
5. 3251^2345^NA^SOLN., 10   %^31-Dec-20^01-Apr-07
```

remove newline and replace cr with newline.  The extra space are in your file...

For literal `^M` instead of `\r` representation you can use `sed 's/\^M//'`

for example:

```
$ echo "here goes^M" | sed 's/\^M//' 
here goes
```

Comment: Thanks @Karafa. I tried this, however All lines are merged together.

Comment: OK, do you have `\r` in your files or literally '^M' two-char representation?  If so, after first `tr` use `sed 's/\^M/\n'`

Comment: No did not work. Sed isnt replacing ^M. It is a '^M' representation.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your input file simply uses `\r\n` (CR-LF) as the newline string instead of just `\n` (LF) and that the lines can contain `\n`. That's very common for files generated in Windows. Here's one way to convert them to `\n` newlines with no `\n`s mid-line as used in UNIX, using GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ cat -v file
1. abc^123-01^NA^xyz 70
   %^11-Sep-12^15-Apr-08^M
2. def^345^NA^NAME^01/10/2006^04/01/2007^M
3. ghi^234-01^NA^company 70
   %^19-Oct-20^04-Jun-07^M
4. jkl^72403831^NA^Org^13-Mar-11^26-Mar-08^M
5. 3251^2345^NA^SOLN., 10
   %^31-Dec-20^01-Apr-010^M

$ awk -v RS='\r\n' '{gsub(/\n/,"")}1' file
1. abc^123-01^NA^xyz 70   %^11-Sep-12^15-Apr-08
2. def^345^NA^NAME^01/10/2006^04/01/2007
3. ghi^234-01^NA^company 70   %^19-Oct-20^04-Jun-07
4. jkl^72403831^NA^Org^13-Mar-11^26-Mar-08
5. 3251^2345^NA^SOLN., 10   %^31-Dec-20^01-Apr-010
```

or to remove the spaces around each `\n` too:

```
$ awk -v RS='\r\n' '{gsub(/\s*\n\s*/,"")}1' file
1. abc^123-01^NA^xyz 70%^11-Sep-12^15-Apr-08
2. def^345^NA^NAME^01/10/2006^04/01/2007
3. ghi^234-01^NA^company 70%^19-Oct-20^04-Jun-07
4. jkl^72403831^NA^Org^13-Mar-11^26-Mar-08
5. 3251^2345^NA^SOLN., 10%^31-Dec-20^01-Apr-010
```

and to access each field in each record:

```
$ awk -v RS='\r\n' -F'^' '{gsub(/\s*\n\s*/,""); print; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print "\t"i, $i}' file
1. abc^123-01^NA^xyz 70%^11-Sep-12^15-Apr-08
        1 1. abc
        2 123-01
        3 NA
        4 xyz 70%
        5 11-Sep-12
        6 15-Apr-08
2. def^345^NA^NAME^01/10/2006^04/01/2007
        1 2. def
        2 345
        3 NA
        4 NAME
        5 01/10/2006
        6 04/01/2007
3. ghi^234-01^NA^company 70%^19-Oct-20^04-Jun-07
        1 3. ghi
        2 234-01
        3 NA
        4 company 70%
        5 19-Oct-20
        6 04-Jun-07
4. jkl^72403831^NA^Org^13-Mar-11^26-Mar-08
        1 4. jkl
        2 72403831
        3 NA
        4 Org
        5 13-Mar-11
        6 26-Mar-08
5. 3251^2345^NA^SOLN., 10%^31-Dec-20^01-Apr-010
        1 5. 3251
        2 2345
        3 NA
        4 SOLN., 10%
        5 31-Dec-20
        6 01-Apr-010
$
```